# Put condition in HTTP request using gatling

Tags: performance, scala, testing, performance-testing, gatling

I want to add condition on http request. like this scenario,
using API,

1. I have one action from where I find 'Action ID'
2. Using that 'Action Id' I check the status of that action which is 'Running/waiting/completed/etc' and save it in variable

*I did this this two steps, Now I want to do*

**3. I have to check status on condition every 20 minutes if status is 'Running', re-check status every 20 minutes if status = 'completed' then exit oR exit after 2 Hours automatically (evenif status is in running state)**

**EDIT:**
Want to put condition like this,

```
Check status = true
{   
    pause for 15minutes
    request once again after 15minutes
    if(status = false)
    {
        exit
    }
    else
    {
        request once again and check status, if true wait for 15minutes
        If total waiting time is more than 2 hours then exit
    }
}
else
{
    exit
}
```

below is the code snippet what I did,

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class LaunchResources extends Simulation {

    val scenarioRepeatCount = Integer.getInteger("scenarioRepeatCount", 1).toInt
    val userCount = Integer.getInteger("userCount", 1).toInt
    val UUID  = System.getProperty("UUID", "24d0e03")
    val username = System.getProperty("username", "p1")
    val password = System.getProperty("password", "P12")
    val testServerUrl = System.getProperty("testServerUrl", "https://someurl.net")

    val httpProtocol = http
        .baseURL(testServerUrl)
        .basicAuth(username, password)
        .connection("""keep-alive""")
        .contentTypeHeader("""application/vnd+json""")

    val headers_0 = Map(
        """Cache-Control""" -> """no-cache""",
        """Origin""" -> """chrome-extension://fdmmgasdw1dojojpjoooidkmcomcm""")

    val scn = scenario("LaunchAction")
        .repeat (scenarioRepeatCount) {
            exec(http("LaunchAResources")
                .post( """/api/actions""")
                .headers(headers_0)
                .body(StringBody(s"""{"UUID": "$UUID", "stringVariables" : {"externalFilePath" : "/Test.mp4"}}"""))
                .check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("WorkflowID")))


        .exec(http("SaveWorkflowStatus")
                .get("""/api/actions/{$wflowid}""")
                .headers(headers_0)
                .check(jsonPath("$.status").saveAs("WorkflowStatus")))

        .asLongAs(session => session.attributes("WorkflowStatus") != false) {
    pause(900)
    .exec(http("SaveWorkflowStatus")
            .get("""/api/actions/${WorkflowID}""")
            .headers(headers_0)
            .check(jsonPath("$.running").saveAs("WorkflowStatus")))

    }

        }


    setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(userCount))).protocols(httpProtocol)
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this `asLongAs(session => session.attributes(response) != "MY STATUS") {
    exec( http().get(). .check(xpath("//status").saveAs(response)  ) }`

so basically this will keep on running till value of response is not equal to MY STATUS .

You can also add other short circuit conditions in asLongAs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have edited my question with exact definition what I want to do. can you please help me on that?

EDIT: Want to put condition like this,

Check status = true
{ ..... }

Comment: I think peter above should solve this as well ...what you need is to block the operation for 20 minutes ,, can you try pause ... I have also not tried it though

Comment: I have tried with asLongAs and added .pause() in it but it throws error. There is something wrong in passing ${workflowStatus}. Updated my code with errors. pls help. Thanks.

Comment: try this session.attributes("WorkflowStatus") $ should not be there ...

Comment: Thanks user666, it worked. Now how can I check whether my action is completed or not? i mean, once it goes in asLongAs loop that action waits for 15minutes --> then once again request  If got status = true then exit else again request. after every 15minutes until 2hours. how to code this? Thanks once again

Comment: User666, For this condition(If waiting time is more than 2hours or WorkflowStatus == True then exit)
Like, Take one variable as a counter and put it into asLongAs condition if counter value=8 then exit.
can you help me?

Comment: try like this .asLongAs(session => (session.attributes(your attribute) != "whatever" ) here the session => is important and should get it working ...

Comment: There is a during method as well can during(duration, counterName, exitASAP) .. i think this might work for you

Comment: Just implemented this,
.asLongAs(session => session.attributes("WorkflowStatus") != "false" && count.getAndIncrement() < 8) {...}

and it worked. 

Do you know How do I put those timed out http requests in 'Failed' state? (I mean those requests which triggered in above scenario are not able to complete within 2 hours of time. I need to put them as Failed)